# Out of memory exception when adding images to image list and displaying them into a list view

Tags: c#, winforms, out-of-memory

I am in the process to making an image gallery where i need to load more than 2 GB images from 1 directory to list view.

when i browse a folder above 200 mb its showing me the error OUT OF MEMORY.

my code is

```
        _filenames = new List<string>();
             DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@root + "gallery");
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
               if (file.Name != "desktop.ini")
                {
                    var image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
                    _filenames.Add(file.Name.ToLower());
                    imageList1.Images.Add(image);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }                           
            listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
            imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(75,75);
            listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
            for (int i = 0; i < imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = new ListViewItem();
                item.ImageIndex = i;
                item.Text = _filenames[i];
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
```

Comment: does 2GB of images not seem quite excessive for a list view? most users wouldn't want to use that much memory to load at once?

Comment: You can say. its exception...

Comment: its stucks even folder size is 503 mb

Comment: I think you should read up on lazy loading in this sort of situation.

Comment: AND WHAT IS THAT???? @jbutler483

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: I have added some pictures name to list string like 0001.jpg, 2345.jpg etc. now how to load images from a directory who's names are there in list string? Above code is for adding all images to image list.. Please help.. @ jbutler483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to (as a first), perform your image operations *before* adding them to the list:

> Performing other operations, such as setting the ColorDepth or
>   ImageSize will cause the Handle to be recreated. Therefore, you should
>   perform these operations before you add images to the ImageList.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Update following clarifications:**

In order to create your own file list then (assuming you have the directory name and file names within the directory) you could create a `FileInfo[]` array as follows:

```
// Prepare the directory and file names
var directoryName = "C:\\Temp\\MyFolder";
var filenames = new List<string>();
filenames.Add("0001.jpg");
filenames.Add("2345.jpg");

// Construct FileInfo array - using System.IO
var files = new FileInfo[filenames.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < filenames.Count; i++)
{
    var fileName = filenames[i];
    files[i] = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directoryName, fileName));
}
```

There are many ways you could construct the `FileInfo[]` array (e.g. LINQ for example), but the above should work fine.

Comment: I have added some pictures name to list string like 0001.jpg, 2345.jpg etc. now how to load images from a directory who's names are there in list string? Above code is for adding all images to image list.. Please help @ ne1410s

Comment: So you have the file names and the directory name in which they reside - and you want to load just these, rather than all files in the directory?  Can't you just construct your own `FileInfo[]` array from these paths then simply iterate that?

Comment: exactly @ ne1410s. but how to do that??

Comment: @Flanker : I've had a go at updating my original answer - so please let me know if it's any good - or if I can help further

Comment: only 1 problem is there now. i want that names of those files which are not present in directory should be displayed after loading those which are present. in simple words FileNotFind Exception. @ ne1410s –

Comment: The `FileInfo` instance should have a property on it called `Exists` which should come in handy.   If you are ever intending to write back to these files, the `IsReadOnly` property is also useful.